# 1st day lua - confused by a for loop

Tags: variables, for-loop, lua, int

Very simple question, but I'm really confused :P

```
> for x = 0, 5, 0.2 do
print (x)
end
```

This loop counts only to 4.8
(one step more with 0.2 would result exactly 5, wouldn't it?)

But the following for-loop counts to 5

```
> for x = 0, 5, 1 do
print (x)
end
```

Can someone explain or refer to the manual, the reason behind these outputs. Maybe I should define the variable as float?

Answer (score 4):

Lua usually represents numbers in [ieee754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE754) [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary64) format ("usually" because the representation actually depends on the underlying C implementation). The [closest number](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046050) to `0.2` in binary64 is `0x3FC999999999999A`, or approximately `0.200000000000000011102230246252`.

The `0.2` in your source code is rounded to this number before the calculation takes place.

Since `0.200000000000000011102230246252` is larger than `2`, the number becomes larger than `5` in the final step, and so the loop ends at approximately `4.8`.

Comment: For a detailed but gentle explanation of floating-point numbers, see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg.

Answer (score 3):

```
for x = 0, 5, 0.2 do print (x) end
```

This numeric `for` loop will add the step `0.2` to initial value `0`, do the processing (`print(x)`) until the value is `<=5`. The problem is, for floating point numbers, `0.2` can't be represented precisely, so there is a little bit rounding. So when you think it should sum as `5`, it probably is a little bit bigger.

For integers that isn't very big, it can be represented precisely in a double precision floating point number, so that's no problem.

---

For your first day of learning Lua, a little tip:

- Use **Lua** as the language name, not LUA or lua.
- Lua has only one number type, that is `double` by default. <sup>* see below</sup>

`*`:This is no longer true. Lua 5.3 introduced a new integer subtype for numbers. See [Changes in the Language](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.1)

Comment: _Lua has only one number type, that is double by default_ - That being said, added integer support is one of the main features planned for the upcoming [Lua 5.3](http://www.lua.org/work/doc/#changes) release.

Comment: @ComicSansMS That's nice to know. I'll remember to come back here and modify the answer when Lua 5.3 releases :)

Comment: @ComicSansMS, so long as it works better than the *horid* "Lua Number" patch they like to foist off on embedded ports. _*shudders*_, it tries to coerce numbers into one of a pair of hidden types and it doesn't always work, producing bizzare error messages.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, when working with floats/doubles in any language and you get some weird stuff happening, search about how floats/doubles are stored in the particular language.

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237773/strange-for-loop-problem)

As **@jbr** already noted, 0.2 is stored as `0.2000000000000000111022302462515654042363166809082031250000000000`, when a for loop runs, it checks if the value is less or equals to 5, and because the sum of these doubles is a bit greater than 5, it doesn't interpret it as a member of this loop and immediately quits.

Answer (score 1):

What you are hitting here is something a lot of people get confused over in Lua. In Lua all the numbers are doubles, this means that not all number have a precise representation, `0.2` is one of those numbers:

```
> print(string.format("%1.64f",math.abs(0.2)))
0.2000000000000000111022302462515654042363166809082031250000000000
```

So what you get here is an accumulated error.

If you try `0.25`:

```
> print(string.format("%1.64f",math.abs(0.25)))
0.2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So

```
for x = 0, 5, 0.25 do
  print(x)
end
```

works as expected, for more information see [Lua fails to evaluate math.abs(29.7 - 30) <= 0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332553/lua-fails-to-evaluate-math-abs29-7-30-0-3/16333241#16333241)